# Where does "aws_eip" resource in terraform file (.tf) gets the value referring "id" attribute in "aws_instance" resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In this page https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html

What is the value of `aws_instance.example.id` as I don't see an attribute called `id` for an instance resource (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second link points to documentation about a data source.

In the page https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html, `"${aws_instance.example.id}"` is referring a resource, not a data source (data sources are preceded by `data.`)

Here is the documentation about aws_instance you're looking for:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#id

It is very important to differentiate between [resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html) and [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) in Terraform ;)

Comment: I found my typo. I was looking at wrong one. Thanks :).

Comment: Hi! If this answer solved the problem please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked:

> id is set to the ID of the found Instance.

In addition to the attributes listed